# Apostrophes issue while passing as parameter

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, apostrophe, htmlspecialchars

i tried to fix an issue with apostrophes but did not succeed. Please have a look into this and suggest me the needful.

I am fetching a value from database which has apostrophes. I am passing the value using a variable into another javascript function. But because of the apostrophe, the function is not executing. Please have a look into below mentioned code.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
$Id = $abc->id;
$str = $abc->street; // output: 111 O'CG street
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_details(<?php echo $Id1;?>,'<?php echo $str;?>')"> 
Display
</a>
```

I tried to use the HTML code using backslash as well. But did not overcome the issue.

**Code with backslash:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_details(<?php echo $Id1;?>,\"<?php echo $str;?>\")"> 
Display
</a>
```

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use addslashes() function.

Like:

```
<?php echo addslashes($str);?>
```

Comment: And stripslashes for the reverse operation

Answer (score 0):

Just change your single quotes to double quotes

```
onclick="show_details(<?php echo $Id1;?>,\"<?php echo $str;?>\")"
```

Comment: That's a valid solution too... but what if the $str contains "? That's why I think it's better (and universal) using addslashes().

Comment: Wow.. using addslashes() really helped me to fix the issue. And its really true that the variable can have no information some point of time (means the value of the variable will be empty).